# How to find specific code lines in Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Suppose we have various `.ipynb` files in different directories.
I know that I wrote some specific code lines in one of these `ipynb`s.
How can I search in which `.ipynb` this code was written from Jupyter notebook interface?

Comment: If it spread across too many blocks, try saving the notebook as .py file and do a simple search  Ctrl + F

Answer (score 0):

Try opening notebooks in visual code and Ctrl+shift+f for searching multiple files.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Besides, I am looking for the way to avoid installation of any additional software. It would be pretty good if there is provided some out-of-box solution.